# How to use an if statement in HAML to control a tag class string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have a condition where if action_name contains "index" then the second class should return "index" only, otherwise, set it to action_name.

I was trying something along these lines:

```
  - if action_name =~ /.*index.*/
    %body{ :class => "#{controller_name} index" }
  - else
    %body{ :class => "#{controller_name} #{action_name}" }
```

Unfortunately I have the remainder of my body in the layout that follows these and it is only displayed for the `else` clause.

I figure there is a more readable one liner that I could use here as well that would perform an if within the line vs the more verbose multiline if statement, but I could use some help here in terms of gettin this to work as expected in HAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here's a one liner:

```
%body{ :class => "#{controller_name} #{(action_name =~ /.*index.*/) ? 'index' : action_name}" }
```

Not that readable though!

Answer (score 3):

I'd put a method in a helper. I like to keep logic out of my views.

**application_helper.rb**

```
def get_class(name)
  "#{controller_name} #{(name =~ /.*index.*/) ? 'index' : name}"
end
```

**view**

```
%body{ :class => get_class action_name }
```

Comment: Good idea... I'll look into that when I have a moment to spare tomorrow.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
%body{:class => "#{controller_name} #{(action_name =~ /[index]/) ? 'index' : action_name}" }
```